# How to horizontally aligned inmobi banner view programmatically in Android?

Tags: android, ads

I tried to add a inmobi banner ads view to my android app programmingly:

```
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams adParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,                        
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        adParams.gravity = Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL | Gravity.TOP;
        activity_.addContentView(inmobiBannerView_, adParams);
```

This works perfectly for Admob banner view, but for Inmobi, the banner is always on top-left corner.

I also tried to other LayoutParams values as well as RelativeLayout, it just does not work.

Answer (score 1):

After countless trial and errors, I found the following code works:

```
        FrameLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(
                FrameLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 
                FrameLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        layoutParams.gravity = Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL;

        inmobiBannerView_.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
        FrameLayout layout = (FrameLayout)activity_.findViewById(android.R.id.content);
        layout.addView(inmobiBannerView_);
```